# GetWindowText malfunktion

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to learn how to make a GUI for a C++ using visual studio. but I have encountered some problems while using the GetWindowText() function. It does not change the LPTSTR title to the text in the textbox and I also get an error when debugging saying: “Exception thrown at 0x74F8207D (user32.dll) in Win32Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x002B8D38.” The code can be seen below what am I doing wrong?

```
#define ID_BUTTON1 1
#define ID_BUTTON2 2
#define ID_TEXT3 3
static HWND hWndTextbox;
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (message)
{
case WM_CREATE:
{
    HMENU hMenubar = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hFile = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hOptions = CreateMenu();

    AppendMenu(hMenubar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hFile, L"File");
    AppendMenu(hMenubar, MF_POPUP, NULL, L"Edit");
    AppendMenu(hMenubar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hOptions, L"Options");

    AppendMenu(hFile, MF_STRING, NULL, L"Exit");
    AppendMenu(hOptions, MF_STRING, NULL, L"option 1");
    AppendMenu(hOptions, MF_STRING, NULL, L"option 2");
        SetMenu(hWnd, hMenubar);

    CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Hello"),
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
        10, 10, 80, 25,
        hWnd, (HMENU) ID_BUTTON1, NULL, NULL);

    static HWND hWndTextbox = CreateWindow(TEXT("edit"), TEXT("tekst goes here"),
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD|WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
        90, 120, 300, 20,
        hWnd, (HMENU) ID_TEXT3, NULL, NULL);

    CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("shiny"),
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
        50, 50, 80, 50,
        hWnd, (HMENU) ID_BUTTON2, NULL, NULL);
}
break;
case WM_COMMAND:
    {
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_BUTTON1) {
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"Button has been clicked", L"title for popup", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_BUTTON2) {
        // create some default vars
        // int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWndTextbox) + 1;
        LPTSTR title = L"test" ;

        GetWindowText(hWndTextbox, title, GetWindowTextLength(hWndTextbox) + 1);
        MessageBox(hWnd, title, L"Message box", MB_OK);
    }
    break;
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}
```

the rest of the code was auto generated by visual studio so I have only included the part where I made changes.

Comment: You aren't supposed to modify a string literal, I believe that's undefined behavior. Set up a `char` or `wchar_t` (or `TCHAR`) array instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [`GetWindowText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx) states that parameter `lpString` is supposed to point to a "buffer that will receive the text", which implies a *writable* buffer.

With the code `LPTSTR title = L"test";` you create a pointer to a string literal which usually is located in read-only memory. When `GetWindowText()` tries to write to that memory, it causes an access violation.

To solve the issue, use a writable buffer like this:

```
// Allocate buffer including terminating null
std::wstring title( GetWindowTextLength(hWndTextbox) + 1, 0 );

// Address of first character is used to obtain pointer to non-const data
// (as opposed to wstring::c_str()).
int size = GetWindowText( hWndTextbox, &title[0], title.size() );

// Resize buffer to the actual text length
title.resize( size );

// MessageBox only needs pointer to const string, so we can use wstring::c_str() here.
MessageBox(hWnd, title.c_str(), L"Message box", MB_OK);
```